# Port D isn't Working as Input

Tags: arduino-uno, port-mapping

I'm using an Atmega328p SMD with 32 pins.  I'm trying to get several pins on Port D to function as inputs.  As outputs, they work fine, but for some reason, not as inputs.  Here's a simple example of what I'm dealing with.

```
void setup() {

DDRB |= (1<<PB3);  //Set up an output on PB3 for an LED
DDRD = B00000000;  //All of Port D set as inputs
DDRC = B00000000;  //All of Port C set as inputs
}

void loop() {

int Power = (PIND & (1 << PORTD5));  //Read input

  if(Power == 1){
PORTB |= (1 << PORTB3);      //set high
  }
  else{
  PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB3);  // set  low  
}
```

I get no response from my LED like this, no matter which pin on Port D I use as an input.  But when I simply change over to Port C, it works fine.

```
int Power = (PINC & (1 << PORTC5));  //Read input
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check if `power` is `1`, but it will never be `1`. Instead it will be `1<<5` or `32`. Better use:

```
if(Power != 0){
  PORTB |= (1 << PORTB3);      //set high
}
else{
  PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB3);  // set  low  
}
```

Comment: That looks like it worked.  But now I have to ask why would it work on Port C as the way I had it?

Comment: Sorry, I figured that out.  I was using PC0, so I guess that would equal 1.  Sorry for the confusion in the example by using PC5, I didn't think that was an issue.

Comment: I was puzzled by that too. Glad you figured it out. Best of luck,